# Exception... "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount" code: "1" nsresult: "0x80530001 (IndexSizeError)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

When i try to delete the row in the table using javascript i get this error

```
Exception... "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"  code: "1" nsresult: "0x80530001 (IndexSizeError)
```

The rows will be correctly deleted but suddenly I get this Index error don't know why please guide me.

code:

```
function deleteRow(tableID,loop) {

  try {

       var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       var rownumber = loop;
       alert(rownumber);                 
         table.deleteRow(rownumber);                      
     }    

catch (e) {
    alert(e);
 }
}
```

Comment: did you chech the index value is less then rows.length ?

Comment: @BalaKrishnan웃 Will check that using alert please wait for 1 min

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert. Google for Chrome/Firefox developer tools.

Comment: @BalaKrishnan웃 I am deleting the row by passing the rowcount

Comment: @dystroy Should we use console.log

Comment: console.log(loop, table.rows, rowCount);

Comment: dont call func if rowNumber = 0 like `if (rownumber == 0) return;`

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi Seems to be good please elaborate

Comment: before `table.deleteRow(rownumber);` write `if (rownumber == 0) return;`

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I tried but it is showing me the same error

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I tried  f (rownumber == 0) return; but i am getting the same error

Comment: replace it out of try-catch.replace it before try-catch block

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi Hi u are telling me to replace if (rownumber == 0) return; before try

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi Still it is not working